# How to encrypt app.config ( Without decrypt method )

Tags: c#, .net, sql, iis, app-config

I want to encrypt my "`ConnectionString`" settings which is located in app.config.
But at the Runtime, I want to use( read `ConnectionString` ) it directly, without decrypt it.

I mean, I don't want to anyone to decrypt the string. There should be NO decryption method.
I'm thinking; it should be like embed .net/asp.net/iis feature to use.
Like "Windows Login" ( you can enter it, use it, but you can't decrypt )

===

An Example Usage; You have small website with some critical data.
You have no money to buy private server,
so you are working on shared server, if the server hacked somehow, 
you application and database will be stolen.
But if you put encrypted connectionstring in app.config,
This will be hard to decrpt it and see what is inside in Database.

Comment: Ok, so - if you can not decrypt it, how is your application going to USE It? BAD NEWS: you are the guy locking his house, throwing the key away and not thinking how to open the door again. If your server can not decrypt the config, then it can not access the database. Case closed, useless configuration.

Comment: Not to mention once the server is compromised, your web.config either will be or is largely irrelevant anyway.

Comment: That which is encrypted will remain so until it is decrypted. I'm afraid it's that simple.

Comment: Maybe you should gear your question around possible alternatives to config files for storing application scoped settings?

Comment: @So guys, how are you protecting your sql data? If I will find winserver2012 zero-day exploit and attack your servers somehow, then you will not have any database protection ?

Comment: @LostInLib If you are hacked you might not be protected, that is correct.  Making it harder to attack can be to not connect your site to the database through usr/pwd but through a service account; then you have to mimic the very user to get to the database.  Another way to lessen the attack vector is to only allow stored procedures - that makes it impossible to anything that is not already implemented.  Then there are many more ways of course.

Comment: Once you find the answer to one-way encryption without decrypting it to see the content you will officially become the worlds richest person ever.

Answer (score 2):

Encrypting and decrypting configuration settings in a config file can be done from the command line using the aspnet_regiis.exe tool.

The details are described in the following MSDN article:

> **[Encrypting and Decrypting Configuration Sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)**

As the tool is mainly intended to be used with Web applications, it expects the config file to be named 'web.config'. This means that you temporarily will have to rename your app.config file to web.config:

```
rename App.config web.config
aspnet_regiis -pef connectionStrings . -prov DataProtectionConfigurationProvider
rename web.config App.config
```

Answer (score 1):

[DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) might be a solution.

You can connect your usr/pwd/credentials to the machine.  JGalloway knows more about this than I.  JGalloway knows more about anything dotnet than I.
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx

If I haven't mixed things up this creates a usr/pwd combination that is bound to the very hardware of the machine.  I.e. change network card and stuff might break.  Also; one cannot create the usr/pwd/creds one machine and then transfer to another.  In short this means that you have to do whatever you have to do on the production machine - might give you a headache if you are targeting continuous delivery.

Caveat: I haven't tried it myself.  Instead I opted for a "regular" encryption.  If someone got hold of my encrypted string and bytecode and reverse engineered it I would be smoked.  But it was enough of security for me.